# No module name 'xmlrpclib' when using Electrum from Command line

Tags: python, python-import, xmlrpclib

I just installed a bitcoin wallet from command line from Electrum.org

heres how i installed it in my user account directory .. /home/user/...

```
sudo pip3 install https://download.electrum.org/2.8.2/Electrum-2.8.2.tar.gz
```

and it installed with no issues.

When i attempt to run the software from command line using 
`electrum` or if i try `electrum help` i get this ImportError

(heres their documentation http://docs.electrum.org/en/latest/cmdline.html)

```
ImportError: No module named 'xmlrpclib'
```

heres the traceback if you are trying to replicate it

```
File "/usr/local/bin/electrum", line 71, in check_imports
import jsonrpclib

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/jsonrpclib/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
from jsonrpclib.jsonrpc import Server, MultiCall, Fault

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/jsonrpclib/jsonrpc.py", line 50, in <module> 
from xmlrpclib import Transport as XMLTrasnport
```

I have done

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get upgrade`

`sudo pip install xmlrpclib`

but have had no avail.

If anyone can provide some insight thatd be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 16):

> The `xmlrpclib` module has been renamed to `xmlrpc.client` in Python
>   3.

So, if you want to use `xmlrpclib`

```
import xmlrpclib
```

Replace that with this:

```
from xmlrpc import client
```

This project has not been updated for two years, so you can find this file `/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/jsonrpclib/jsonrpc.py` and change

```
from xmlrpclib import Transport as XMLTransport
from xmlrpclib import SafeTransport as XMLSafeTransport
from xmlrpclib import ServerProxy as XMLServerProxy
from xmlrpclib import _Method as XML_Method
```

to

```
from xmlrpc.client import Transport as XMLTransport
from xmlrpc.client import SafeTransport as XMLSafeTransport
from xmlrpc.client import ServerProxy as XMLServerProxy
from xmlrpc.client import _Method as XML_Method
```

---

Also you can use `2to3` to convert the source:

```
2to3 -w jsonrpc.py
```

Then change

```
line 168 from http.client import HTTP, HTTPConnection
line 186     class UnixHTTP(HTTP):
```

To

```
line 168 from http.client import HTTPConnection
line 186     class UnixHTTP(HTTPConnection):
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: "no module named client"

Comment: thank you for that. i no longer get that ImportError, however im getting a different one and the answer isnt as simple as the one you just gave me..

the httplib library also changed to http.client... so i made that necessary change but now im getting a 
     cannot import name 'HTTP' 

in the line 
     from http.client import HTTP, HTTPConnection